# Robot cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, awtrobot

I tried to make program, which moves mouse to some coordinates (x, y). I have this error:

> Multiple markers at this line
>   - MoveMouse cannot be resolved

My code:

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;

public class Temr 
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException 
    {
        MoveMouse tvoi = new MoveMouse(40, 30);     
        /*  Multiple markers at this line
        - MoveMouse cannot be resolved 
         to a type
        - MoveMouse cannot be resolved 
         to a type */

    }

    public void MoveMouse(int a, int b) throws AWTException
    {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        int x;
        int y;
        x = a;
        y = b;
        robot.mouseMove(x, y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

MoveMouse is a function and not a class.

Replace the code in the main function with

```
Temr temr = new Temr();
temr.MoveMouse(40, 30);
```

Comment: Thanks! Can i too make MoveMouse like class?

Answer (score 1):

1. MoveMouse is a method so you are not supposed to do it like this.
2. If you want to call moveMouse from main method you need to declare it static.
3. Code convention for java method names is:

   > Methods should be verbs, in mixed case with the first letter lowercase, with the first letter of each internal word capitalized.

Source: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

I did a little refactoring and this code works on my machine:

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Test
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException
  {
    moveMouse(300, 300);
  }

  public static void moveMouse(int a, int b) throws AWTException
  {
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.mouseMove(a, b);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MoveMouse class

```
public class MoveMouse {

    Robot ro;

    public MoveMouse(int x, int y) throws AWTException{
        ro = new Robot();
        ro.mouseMove(x, y);
        ro.delay(1000); // 1 second delay
    }
}
```

and you can call it in your class like

```
public class TestMove {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException{

        new MoveMouse(500, 500);

    }
}
```